# Home networking using Raspberry Pi and Python - Network Bridges

Tags: python, networking, raspbian, scapy, forwarding

Basically I want to be able to increase the range of my home network via some Raspberry Pi running some wireless python bridge software I am going to write.

The setup would be as follows:

```
                Internet
                    |
                    |                                                           192.168.0.4
PC1                 |                                                             Laptop1                                                  
   |---------------Switch(Gateway)---------------Pi1-------Pi2---------Pi3------------|
PC2                192.168.0.1              192.168.0.2           192.168.0.3     Laptop2                  
                                                                                192.168.0.5
```

Should mean that both Laptop 1 and Laptop 2 would be able to connect to the Internet as if they were connected to the switch like the 2 PCs (So could ping google etc).

I want to write the bridging code my self to run on the Pi just out of my own interest and practice in python networking.

I currently have the interface facing the laptops on Pi3 setup as an access point thanks to hostapd and ad-hoc connections between all the Pi. One of Pi1's interfaces is connected to the switch as you would normally connect to an AP.

Each Pi has 2 wlan interfaces (wlan0 & wlan1).

I have been using [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) to sniff the packets being sent from the laptops and then forward on using sendp after modifying the destination and source MAC addresses.

Using wireshark i can see that if i send a scapy constructed packet from one of the laptops it does get sent out on Pi1 interface facing the switch (and so should be received by the switch, thus updating its table to say any packets with destination IP address of 192.168.0.2 or 192.168.0.3 must be sent to the MAC address of the interface on Pi1 facing the Switch), however no Internet connection can be established by the laptops.

I wonder if this is because scapy does not truly redirect/manipulate the original packets and just creates a copy for you to play with and so would not work for what I desire?

I have read from other posts that perhaps [Divert Sockets](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Divert-Sockets-mini-HOWTO.html) may be the correct approach? But have also read that they are not supported anymore?

Also as it stands I am setting up the IP addresses of the Pi and Laptops statically and only forwarding on IPv4 packets (The Pi3 AP does not have any DHCP/NAT/DNS servers running, just simply allows the laptops to connect to the Pi).

This is my first attempt at such a project so the problem could be really simple so I either have not noticed or my understanding might be fundamentally incorrect. Any help or advice would be much appreciated as this is driving me crazy. (Code needs some major refactoring, but want to get the thing working first)

Thanks for taking a look!

```
        if packet[Ether].src in interfaceMACs:#If packet sent from 1 of the interfaces ignore
            print "Drop from bridge"
            return

        if packet[Ether].dst in inTable:#If the destination is on the same segment as the recieving interface ignore
            print "Drop same segment"
            return

        if packet[Ether].dst == 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff':#Ignore broadcasts #TODO: need to support broadcasts
            print "Drop broadcast"
            return




        if IP in packet:
            if packet[IP].dst == myIP:  # When packet is destined for this interfaces
                print "reached destination - this interface"
                return

            if packet[IP].dst == otherIP:  # When packet destined for far side interface
                print "Reached destination - Other interface"
                return

            newDstMac = searchTable(outTable, packet[IP].dst)
            if newDstMac is None:#If final destination is not on this bridges out interface
                if len(outTable) == 1:#Resolve which host is the bridge
                    packet[Ether].dst = outTable.keys()[0]#Send to the only device connected to this interface (Another bridge)
                else:#If more than 1 destination host, would be the gateway and multiple hosts, so find the gateway and send packet to it.
                    gatewayMAC = searchTable(outTable, "192.168.0.1")
                    if gatewayMAC is None:#No gateway, problem
                        print "ERROR!!!!!!!!!!! NO GATEWAY"
                    else:
                        packet[Ether].dst = gatewayMAC



            else:#means the final destination is on this interface
                packet[Ether].dst = newDstMac#Then set the destination MAC to the final destination

            packet[Ether].src = self.outMAC#Set source as the interface sending the packet
            sendPacket(outInterface, packet)
            self.packetCount += 1


        print self.packetCount
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Cheers, edited to leave only the logic for the processing of the packets as i can send and receive them fine (but only if i use scapy to construct the packets on the laptops then send). 

So unsure if the problem is even the code or a fundamental issue with my approach.

Comment: nah, physical bridge not same to software bridge !

Comment: Could you please expand?

Are you saying I would need to make physical bridges in order to get this type of setup working?

Thanks